# Why wasn't the Torah given earlier?

Tags: torah-reading, creation, har-sinai

The world existed for over 2000 years before the Torah was given en masse. If the Torah and our fulfilling of it, is the point of creation, why was it given after so long?

If people could please answer with some sources or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: God had to wait for the conditions to be such that a critical subset of the people will accept the Torah.  Even so, it contains many concessions to the spirit of the times, without which it would not have been accepted.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi We agree that the Torah had to "allow" many concessions it did not want, including laws of slavery and sacrifices, otherwise they would have rejected it. However, revelation must exist in its entirety from the very beginning of human creation and not a long time after.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is given by Rabbi Naftali ben Shimon Hertz Ginzburg, in his commentary called [Naftali Seva Ratzon on the Pesach Haggadah](https://www.sefaria.org/Naftali_Seva_Ratzon_on_Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_The_Four_Sons.1.1?ven=Rabbi_Mark_Greenspan&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Rav Ginzburg explains that the Torah did not reject the earlier generations, but *they* rejected the Torah.

It started with Avraham Avinu, who began to spread the Torah to the nations.

> It was only in the time of Abraham that the teachings of Torah were
> revealed. The Torah says, that “Abraham made souls in Haran;” the
> Aramaic translation explains that this means that Abraham taught Torah
> to others; it implies that the Torah began to be revealed in the time
> of Abraham.

But after reading this, the question might occur:

> If the Torah was to be revealed after two thousand years, why wasn’t it revealed immediately in the time of Abraham?

Rav Ginzburg explains that in one of the poets we recite on Shavuos, it says that that the Torah could not be given in the time of Isaac because he flattered Esau <sup>1</sup>

> Jacob was not worthy of receiving the Torah n the Bible says of him:
> “My ways are hidden from the Lord”

Rav Ginzburg goes on to explain that:

> It would appear, then, that Isaac or Jacob were both willing to accept it but they were not worthy of receiving. The Torah did not want to fall into their hands. Ishmael and Esau were both offered the Torah and they rejected it; Ishmael rejected it because he didn’t want to accept the commandment, “Do not commit adultery,” and Esau because he rejected, “Do not murder.” The Torah did not reject them; they rejected the Torah!

So, according to this opinion, the people before Moshe's generation did not accept the Torah with open hands. Moshe and his generation eventually did.

*<sup>1</sup>  Isaac favored Esau over Jacob! He could not be trusted to give the Torah to Jacob so the Torah was not given in his time*

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't the Torah exist at the very beginning of creation instead of a long time after? Isn't it unjust to deprive millions born before the Torah of the 'divine wisdom'? Many Jews struggled with this question. Therefore, tradition came up with the idea that Abraham observed the Torah before it was revealed.

In Genesis 26:4 and 5, God tells Isaac that he will give him the land of Canaan, “because Abraham listened to my voice and kept my charge, commandments, statutes, and laws.”

Rashi, to Midrash Genesis Rabbah 79:7, 92:4, and 95:2, the Babylonian Talmud, Yevamot 21, and other sources, states that Abraham observed the entire Torah even including the rabbinical enactments. Nachmanides adds that others observed the Torah before it was revealed.

Contrary to Rashi and Nachmanides, however, the Rambam writes in the Mishneh Torah that Abraham had just eight mitzvot: the Seven Noachide Laws plus circumcision. According to the Rambam, Abraham did not have the Torah. He reads the many rabbinical statements that the patriarchs observed the entire Torah as hyperbolic sermons highlighting the importance of Torah observance. It is not meant to be taken literally. Besides, if the patriarchs observed the Torah, the Torah would have mentioned it.

Comment: The Torah does mention Abraham observing the Torah.  God tells Abraham’s son Isaac that he will receive blessings…
־שָׁמַ֥ע אַבְרָהָ֖ם בְּקֹלִ֑י וַיִּשְׁמֹר֙ מִשְׁמַרְתִּ֔י מִצְוֺתַ֖י חֻקּוֹתַ֥י וְתוֹרֹתָֽי
...because Abraham obeyed my voice, and kept my charge, my commandments, My laws, and My Torah. [Gen. 26:5]

Comment: According to Spinoza, Abraham had received no special laws from God. When the Torah states that he observed the worship, the precepts, the statutes, and the laws of God (Gen. 26:5), they must be interpreted to mean the statutes, the precepts, and the laws of king Melchisedek.

Comment: @Shmuel IIRC we don't generally pasken according to Spinoza...

Comment: @יהושעק No, but why can't we rely on his commentary to understand the Torah?

Comment: @Shmuel.. because it's outright keffira

Comment: @יהושעק How is his interpretation of that verse keffira? Spinoza was a Jewish philosopher.

Comment: Excellent question, @Shmuel! According to Jewish law, you actually have to be Jewish to be a heretic. The rabbis of his time determined his work to be heresy based on his views of G-d, and they went so far as to put him in herem. Subsequent generations have ratified this decision.

Comment: @יהושעק Spinoza was declared a heretic not by "the rabbis" as there is no such thing as "the rabbis". Spinoza was declared a heretic by the Amsterdam community. He was declared a heretic not because of his theological views but for political reasons because his theological views were a danger to the Jewish community due to surrounding Christian fundamentalists.

Comment: @יהושעק There is no such notion of theological heresy in the Talmudic tradition because the Talmudic rabbis did not codify any binding theological dogma. There is no term heresy in the Bible, and in the Talmudic tradition heresy is only a behavioral concept and not a theological concept at all.

Comment: @יהושעק Spinoza never converted to Christianity. This is strong evidence that Spinoza does not fit the Talmudic conception of heresy as one who scorns tradition. Thus, there is no basis for continuing to regard him as a heretic. And, there is no basis in the Talmudic tradition for regarding him as a heretic because of his theological views. Spinoza was not a heretic!